# How to download MP3 files from Dictionary.com In Matlab?

Tags: matlab, audio, web, dictionary, mp3

I am writing a script that needs to download and play audio files (based on vocabulary words) that are located in a separate .xls file. I want to download the audio for proper pronunciation using Dictionary.com but cannot figure a systmatic way to get the audio.

For example the url for the word "fatuity" is

http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/F00/F0058700.mp3

But for the word "fun" is

http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/F04/F0416100.mp3

how can I query Dictionary.com and download the associated audio? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building the query with the Fbla/Fblabla is a little difficult, but getting the desired link from dictionary.com is possible. Something like this seems to work:

```
word = 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious'; % the word that is to be found

% build the query for dictionary.com by adding the word and read the url
r = urlread(sprintf('http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/%s',word));

% examine the resulting string that contains the html 
try
    % find the index of a certain matching sentence that indicates the beginning and end of the query
    matchIdx = strfind(r,'audio/ogg"> <source src="http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/');
    endIdx = strfind(r, '.mp3"></a>');

    % some tuning with indexes results in the exact url that needs to be called
    % hopefully, the matchIdx and endIdx are found only once - if more, there is an error
    mp3url = r(matchIdx+141:endIdx+3);

    % if there is no match, the url is empty, which is also undesirable
    assert(~isempty(mp3url));

catch e
    % catch the above errors (the mp3url cannot be constructed or is empty), and maybe others
    % (if this becomes a function, some nice pointers of what went wrong should be added)
    error('Could not find url.');
end

% query for the mp3 and store the result
file = 'temp.mp3';
urlwrite(mp3url,file);

% read the just stored file and play!
[x,Fs] = audioread(file);
soundsc(x,Fs);
```

Comment: This is very useful--I am trying to make sense of the code--could you add a few comments to guide me through it? (still not fluent matlab). How where you able to get the link for audio file?

Comment: Ok - done. For more help, read the matlab manuals on [urlread](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html), [audioread](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html), [soundsc](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/soundsc.html), etc.

Comment: Thanks again! I am using MATLAB R2010a and don't have "audioread' function. How should I play the MP3 files. Any suggestions?